# How to define acronyms in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, acronyms, context-mkiv

The `acronym` packages allows one to easily create and display acronyms, with a simple syntax, like `\ac{usb}`. The first time this is called, is will say “Universal Serial Bus (USB)”, but after that, just “USB”. I found nothing about this in the documentation, but this [article on PDF-strings](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/PDF-strings) seems to offer similar functionality, but the example seems incomplete. How can I define and display acronyms in ConTeXt?

Comment: See manual chapter 12.2 - Synonyms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theory behind this is easy, if you don't need to index the acronyms.

```
\def\newacronym#1#2#3{% #1 = key, #2 = abbreviated form, #3 = expanded form
  \expandafter\def\csname ac@#1\endcsname{%
    #3~(#2)%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname ac@#1\endcsname{#2}%
   }%
}
\def\ac#1{\csname ac@#1\endcsname}

\newacronym{usb}{USB}{Universal Serial Bus}
\newacronym{ml}{ML}{Murphy's Law}

Here's \ac{usb} and \ac{ml}; let's see that \ac{usb} works 
not according to \ac{ml}.

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: That's not a ConTeXt solution and the question was explicitly about ConTeXt. Use of def in ConTeXt is discouraged.

Comment: @helcim So what? I explained the theory around defining acronyms; adapting it to ConTeXt should be easy. I'm quite surprised the other answer, which uses `\def` has not even a comment of the same kind.

Comment: Yes, the other answer should have such comment as well. Maybe I'm too pedantic about it, but when you look for ConTeXt solutions to ConTeXt questions  here and find so many answers giving LaTeX (which is specifically counterproductive) or Plain TeX solutions  it's getting much less helpful than it could be.

Comment: @helcim Perhaps, if the documentation for ConTeXt was more easily accessible, it could be easier to provide conforming answers. For instance, I found `\definesynonyms` in the ConTeXtgarden wiki: it is described as a command with four arguments, but there is no mention at all about what the second and fourth arguments do. And the commands don't do what the OP is looking for, that is, distinguishing between first and subsequent usages.

Comment: Well, yes. But it is getting better. `\definesynonyms` is explained with examples in the ConTeXt manual. I have already developed a habit of checking first contextgarden, then tex.stackexchange, the manual (which should really come first), details.pdf, ntg-list, style.pdf and the remaining ConTeXt manuals and not so seldom the source. I agree, one complete source of information would make things easier, but I doubt it is possible to have it now.

Comment: @helcim I'm looking at the manual: on page 79 you can see two pieces of code using `\def`. Is it discouraged or not? One has to decide about this; if it is really discouraged, then it should *not* appear in the manual. Look for `\def` in the LaTeX manual, for instance.

Answer (score 12):

The context version of this functionality is called 'synonyms', types of which are defined using `\definesynonyms`. The wiki page for [definesynonyms](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definesynonyms) contains some examples, but in short:

```
\definesynonyms[acronym][acronyms][\infull]

\acronym[VVV]{vvv}{Bureau of Tourist Information}
\starttext
The Dutch \VVV\ (\infull{VVV}) can provide you with the tourist information on Hasselt.
\stoptext
```

There now also a `\setupsynonyms[acronyms]` and `\placelistofacronyms`. That are used to produce a list of (used or all) acronyms.

As far as I know, ConTeXt does not have a built-in feature for 'first use'.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question but needed indexing. Also, my project contains many loose files, so I don't want to search for first occurances myself.

```
\definesynonyms[acron][acronyms][\fullac] % Define acronyms as context synonyms

% Define a new macro
\def\ac#1{
  \ifcsname AcroUsed#1\endcsname
    % If the acro was already used, return the acronym
    \csname #1\endcsname
  \else
    % Otherwise, set as used, print full and acro
    \fullacro{#1} (\csname #1\endcsname)
    \expandafter\def\csname AcroUsed#1\endcsname{1}
  \fi
}
```