# Check for first occurrence of element in chapter

Tags: macros, chapters, counters

I'm writing a text containing several chapters. In addition, I use about 50 acronyms. Now I would like to expand the acronym in each chapter, but only at its first occurrence. For this, I'm thinking of a macro like

```
\newcommand{\acronym}[2]{%
   % if first occurence in chapter
   \emph{#1} (#2}
   % else
   #2
}
```

The macro describes the command I'm planning to use in my text, e.g., "this is a \acronym{very simple}{VS} example". All acronyms do neither contain white spaces or special characters. In contrast, acronyms are only built of letters.

So I think it is possible with counters, but I have no clue how to start. A counter for each acronym? Or check the sectioning counter?

EDIT: since my package list is already quite long, I would prefer a solution without an additional package. If this is not possible, ok, but normally, there is a way without a package, e.g., use simple tabular and calculate column widths manually.

Comment: Why don't you use one of the package meant for this? E.g. acro or (larger) glossaries?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I extended my question

Comment: A basic thing is that the first ocurrence of the command redefines itself (something like `\gdef\…{#2}`) and then the rest of them only the second part would show up. By the way, is `\acronym` *the command* you are gonna use in your document, or is it the *generator* of those commands? In that case you would need another argument which is the command itself.

Comment: You will need a dedicated acronym counter which is reset at \chapter: the section counter is not reliable as it is possible that you use your acronym only in the third section. And you additionally need for each acronym some test if it has been used in this chapter. Check the code of acro or acronym to find out how they do this.

Comment: Manuel and Ulrike, I would provide a 50 points bounty for a complete code example :-)

Comment: [Related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55050/how-to-define-acronyms-in-context/55055#55055).

Comment: Are there only a few acronyms or hundreds of them? A few one should not pose a problem, but allocating hundreds of counters is not a good idea? And are your acronyms build from just one word, without whitespace in between or special characters?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I edited my question

Comment: I don't need points. I like to find solutions for new problems but I don't like not to spent my time to rewrite the code already existing in various good packages. @ChristianHupfer: You only need one counter + the acro package: The first acronym in a chapter can then call \acresetall.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I have not used the `acro` package so far.

Comment: @strauberry: I added a quick hack, but I suppose, I accidentally switched the meaning of `#1` and `#2` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer awesome, thank you! I think I will figure out the meaning of #1 and #2 :-) As promised, I will start a bounty as soon as it is possible!

Comment: @strauberry: Citing Shakespeare: *As you like it* ;-)

Comment: @strauberry: What about your last lines in your post, where you are saying something about a table and column width? Is it connected to this question?

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newrobustcmd{\ProvideAcronymCounter}[1]{%
\ifltxcounter{#1}{%
}{%
\newcounter{#1}[chapter]
}}

\newcommand{\MyAcronym}[2]{%
  \ProvideAcronymCounter{#2Counter}
  \ifnumequal{\number\value{#2Counter}}{0}{
   % if first occurence in chapter
   \emph{#2} {#1}
   \refstepcounter{#2Counter}
 }{   % else
   #1}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First one}
\blindtext[10]

\MyAcronym{Shakespeare}{An author}

\MyAcronym{Shakespeare}{An author}

\MyAcronym{Shakespeare}{An author}


\chapter{Second chapter}
\blindtext[5]

\MyAcronym{Shakespeare}{An author}



\end{document}
```

[image]